# Пересечение уникальных комбинаций

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть данные вида

```
select 1 a, 2 b, 3 c, 'A' space from dual
    union all
select 1, 2, 3, 'B' from dual
```

Уникальные комбинации полей a, b, c. Могут встречать в записях с разными значениями столбца space (назовем это признаком пространства). Есть ли элегантная возможность, используя преимущества pl/sql - диалекта определить

1. Встречается ли уникальная комбинация в других пространствах или только в одном
2. Сколько и где находится таких уникальных комбинаций

Мой мозг смог из себя выжать только этого монстра )) :

```
with t(a, b, c, space) as
(
    select 1, 1, 3, 'A' from dual
    union all
    select 1, 2, 3, 'A' from dual
    union all
    select 1, 2, 3, 'B' from dual
    union all
    select 1, 4, 3, 'B' from dual
    union all
    select 1, 1, 3, 'C' from dual
    union all
    select 1, 1, 3, 'C' from dual
    union all
    select 3, 1, 3, 'C' from dual
)
select count(1), a, b, c from
(
  select distinct a, b, c, space from t
)
group by a, b, c
```

Подскажите, как бы вы решили такую задачу.

Comment: `SELECT a,b,c,COUNT(DISTINCT space) FROM t GROUP BY a,b,c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, собственно Akina уже дал ответ в комментариях, но можно к нему еще красивостей прикрутить. Добавить список (`listagg` требует версии 11.2+) и перенести `distinct` в подзапрос, чтобы избавиться от дубликатов в списке пространств:

```
with t(a, b, c, space) as
(
    select 1, 1, 3, 'A' from dual
    union all
    select 1, 2, 3, 'A' from dual
    union all
    select 1, 2, 3, 'B' from dual
    union all
    select 1, 4, 3, 'B' from dual
    union all
    select 1, 1, 3, 'C' from dual
    union all
    select 1, 1, 3, 'C' from dual
    union all
    select 3, 1, 3, 'C' from dual
)

SELECT a,b,c,COUNT(space) spaces_count, 
       listagg(space, ',') within group (order by space) spaces_list
  FROM (select distinct * from t) 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT space) > 1
 GROUP BY a,b,c

           A          B          C    SPACES_COUNT  SPACES_LIST   
  ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------  -----------
           1          1          3               2  A,C
           1          2          3               2  A,B
```

> используя преимущества pl/sql

Преимущества PL/SQL - они, вообще говоря, тут совсем ни при чем. Это задача как раз для SQL.

Comment: Я имел ввиду диалект SQL. За ответ - спасибо.

Comment: @АнатолийЭрнст PL/SQL не диалект SQL, это ЯП.

Comment: Я имел ввиду SQL-диалект. SQL же у Oracle отличается немного от стандартного SQL. Функции различные, (+) и т.п. Разве не прав?

Comment: @АнатолийЭрнст Отличается, но не настолько, чтобы эта задача решалась сильно по-разному в разных СУБД. А (+) - это всего лишь такой способ записи `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN`.